# How to create an input range slider in Google Sheets (is it possible)

Tags: google-sheets, slider

What we essentially want is a Data Validation field where the display is a draggable input slider, rather than a Chip, Arrow or Plain Text. Is this possible in Google Sheets? Clearly there is not a **Draggable Slider** option for the Display style for data validation fields. Is there any other way to achieve this in Google Sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. You cannot inject HTML in Sheet cells, and there isn't even a [validation rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria) that would fit a slider. `VALUE_IN_LIST/RANGE` doesn't work because the values could be other than numerical, and `NUMBER_BETWEEN` would also require to figure out the smallest step that the slider can take, which it currently does not do ([Excel does this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-scroll-bar-or-spin-button-to-a-worksheet-f8443be3-ff00-4cad-bb2f-bf0f88ebf5bb) and calls it "incremental change").

Your only option could be to use a [custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title) with Google Apps Script and build the slider with HTML, which can then [communicate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) back to the Sheet. Unless you're really committed to this slider it's probably not worth building an entire HTML interface for this unless you plan to have a full form, and if you want to set the slider on several cells it just sounds unfeasible.

Comment: i had a feeling this was the case. makes sense